# Which Marvel cosmic entities are unique in the multiverse?

Tags: marvel

On many occasions we've seen a "Galactus from another universe", which seems to indicate that each universe has its own Galactus.  On the other hand, the Living Tribunal is supposed to maintain the balance between universes, so it seems there's only one Living Tribunal (and so one One-Above-All) in the multiverse.  But what about other cosmic beings, like Eternity, or Death?  Is there a different one in each universe, or are they unique?  What about The Stranger, who was once part of the Living Tribunal?  What about Celestials?  (Obviously there are lots of celestials, but does each of them have a copy of themselves in each universe?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Goblin Entity](http://marvel.wikia.com/Goblin_Entity_%28Earth-1298%29) appears to be unique across the entire multiverse;

[image]

As is [Rachel Summers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_Summers#cite_note-Uncanny_X-Men_.23462-2) from Earth-811

[image]

And Ahymor/Anihilus from the [Negative Zone](http://marvel.wikia.com/Ahmyor_%28Earth-295%29), since there are no alternates to the Negative Zone

[image]

[Mojo](http://marvel.com/universe/Mojo) certainly claims to be unique but [word of god](http://marvel.wikia.com/Talk:Gaveedra_Seven_%28Mojoverse%29) is that he's a big fat liar

[image]

And [Mojo Longshot](http://marvel.wikia.com/Longshot_%28Mojoverse%29)

[image]

[Immortus](http://marvel.com/universe/Immortus) is an alternate of Kang but is considered to be unique due to his association with Limbo

[image]

The [Marquis of Death](http://www.comicvine.com/the-marquis-of-death/4005-59172/) has travelled extensively across the multiverse (for a billion years) and hasn't met an alternate of himself

[image]

The [Moon Knight](http://www.comicvine.com/marc-spector-moon-knight-42-multiverse-madness/4000-36153/) is unique because he's killed all of his alternates in order to absorb their power (kinda like Jet Li in "the one")

[image]

Comment: "Unique because I killed all my alternates" doesn't really seem the same as "unique" - especially if one assumes that a new alternate universe is created whenever someone makes a choice (or even just a "significant" choice), as seems the case in the *What If?* series. And Annihilus has definitely shown up in *What If?* (1977: # 42, December 1983), with no indication that he was the same Annihilus we see in the 616.

Comment: @RDFozz - The implication is that he's been successful since then. Note that the multiverse in Marvel isn't created by decisions, it's just kinda there.

Comment: Most (if not all) of the stories from the *What If?* series are considered as happening elsewhere in the multiverse, and almost all of those story revolve around X happening instead of Y in a past story. I'm not saying that every multiverse meets that criterion; but some clearly do, with the implication that new multiverses are being created all the time (or that the number of multiverses is basically infinite - hard to kill infinity - 1 Moon Knights, mathematically speaking).

Comment: What about the phoenix force? or The phoenix

Comment: @SeasonalShot - This isn't an exhaustive list. Feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: Mojo (http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mojo_Adams_(Earth-1610)), Longshot(http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Arthur_Centino_(Earth-1610)) and Annihilus(http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Annihilus_(Earth-1610)) all have alternate versions in the Ultimates universe.

Comment: What about America Chavez?

Comment: @shanu - She has alternate versions in the Ultimates universe and we also see her doing stuff on Earth-616, Earth-15928 (Hawkeye-'verse), Earth-20368 and a bunch of other incarnations.